# objective c pulling content from website

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to pull some HTML content from a website using a `UIWebView`. Below is the code. I know that using `[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];` but the above is not working.

Could you guys please help me with which part I exactly have to insert the code to work? If any changes or modifications need to be done in the code. I'd be so grateful. I'm a newbie. The below code just shows the HTML content scrambled.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *urlAddress=@"http://www.firesky.com/";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    //NSURLRequest *requestObj=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSError *error; 
    NSString *googlepage = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url
            encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
    //[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"]; 
    [webView loadHTMLString:googlepage baseURL:nil];   
    [webView release];
}
```

Comment: remove that last line which releases the webview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Load the page into the `UIWebView` as normal:

   ```
   [webView loadRequest:
           [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                        [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]]];
   ```
2. When the page is loaded, run your JavaScript.

I used FireBug to debug my scripts in browser before I embed them in the app. It makes the workflow a little more efficient.

Comment: i used the above code it loaded ...could u help me under which method i got to  insert dis javascript [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"]; could u help ... i m totally new to dis

Comment: Set your view controller as delegate of UIWebView. Then add method - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView.
And insert your java script execution inside it.

Comment: i m getting dis warning local declaration of webview hides instance variable

Comment: in delegate function argument name (webView) is the same with your UIViewController member name. rename function argument or class member.

Comment: thanks able to strip de warning its loads the site google.com..but not de html content..is der something wrong with my javascript

Comment: Hi @Evgen, i have show firebug from uiwebview, with your style, but now i need to hide it. can you tell me how to hide the firebug programmatically?