# How to get contents from HTML or JS using Objective c?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, html, parsing

My boss is asking me to get the list of songs info from the following page:
http://mp3.sogou.com/music.so?query=love%20me%20like%20you%20do&st=1

So If I use CHrome to open this link, I won't see any HTML contents regarding to the list of songs. However, if I right click and choose inspect elements, I can see all the info regarding to each song. 
I dont' know anything about this HTML thing. Is it dynamic HTML or JS? I need to write some codes in Objective c to get the song list info. How can I do it? Can some one guide me to the right direction please?
[image]

[image]

Comment: This link helps you. There is a explanation how to get html content.


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590805/objective-c-get-page-content

Comment: For example: I can see that the following may related to this list of song: <ul class="music_list" id="song_ul"> but How can I get the contents?

Comment: for your needs..check out [Kimonolabs](https://www.kimonolabs.com) which will help you to convert a webpage into Restful API. so you can use that like a web service in your app. This software will crawl and scrap the webpage and will give you the required details